# Confusion regarding orthonormal basis of $L^2[0, 1]$, in requiring $f(0) = f(1)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, orthonormal, hamel-basis

Let us consider here the continuous elements of $L^2$.

It is often stated that the family $e_k(x) = e^{-2 \pi i k x}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0, 1]$, in that a function can be written as
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_k e_k(x), 
$$
for an appropriate complex sequence $c_k$.

However, my confusion is that, since $e_k(0) = e_k(1) =1$ for all $k$, it would seem that this representation forces
$$
f(0) = f(1).
$$

Is there a calculation mistake here? Or is it an issue with point evaluation in $L^2[0, 1]$? If it is the latter, is there a way to change the basis $e_k$ such that a valid point-wise representation holds everywhere (say for continuous representatives/elements of $L^2$)?

For instance, what about the function $f(x) = x$?

---

A more rigorous version of my second question goes as follows. Is there an orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}$ for $L^2[0, 1]$ such that for continuous elements of $C[0, 1]$ there exists a sequence $c_k$
where the the partial sums $f_N = \sum_{|k|\leq N} c_k e_k$
$$
\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x) - f_N(x)| \to 0, \quad \mbox{as}~N \to \infty?
$$

Comment: From "orthonormal basis" we may conclude that the series $f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_k e_k(x)$ converges in the mean of order $2$, not that it converges pointwise.  [Proof is from Bessel's inequality.]

Comment: Ok, so regarding my second question, is there any way to have such a valid pointwise representation for sufficiently smooth/continuous functions?

Comment: I added a more specific version of my second question: since we are looking for valid point wise convergence, I ask if there is a ONB of $L^2$ that permits the series to converge uniformly for the continuous elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is entirely reasonable! Yes, it should come as a shock when one first learns that "convergence" of Fourier series can have different, inequivalent, senses. From a reasonable beginner's viewpoint, *of_course* "convergence" means "pointwise". Duh. Oop, but Fourier series don't reliably do that. As some sort of consolation-prize, we *do* have $L^2$ convergence... which is simply not-at-all equivalent to pointwise convergence. Truly, this stunned me when I first understood the fact. Wow. Oof.

(Ok, yes, there is Carleson's theorem, that an $L^2$ function's Fourier series *does* converge almost everywhere (to that function...))

Further, yes, there is the mysterious connection between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, and similarly for derivatives, in whatever sense. Yes, of course, the relevant exponentials have equal values at both ends. The point is that Fourier series most naturally are expansions of *periodic* functions (of whatever sort), that is, of functions on the circle (pulled-back to make periodic functions on the line... or functions on an interval). That is, the natural object on which Fourier series live is not necessarily an *interval*, but maybe a *circle*. Still, yes, there are other boundary-value ODE situations that do specifically refer to intervals...

So, to my mind, the most natural way to understand Fourier series is to think of them as giving functions on the circle. Ok.

For pointwise values? Differentiability? Yes, this can get entangled with the endpoint-value confusion. For example, yes, with the function that's $x$ on $[0,2\pi]$ (or similar), the endpoint values don't match. Not only cannot the Fourier series "converge to both values" at the two endpoints, but, in addition, that very issue makes the whole Fourier series converge much more delicately on the whole interval!!! This is even more mysterious... :)

Of course, there is much more that can be said about convergence of Fourier series... :)